# Alexander duality formulation + Jordan-Brouwer separation

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, manifolds

In Davis & Kirk LNAT p.71 there is written:
[image]

(1) How does this imply the [Alexander duality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander_duality) $\tilde{H}^k(A)\cong \tilde{H}_{n-k-1}(\mathbb{S}^n\!\setminus\!A)$?

(2) Is it assumed that the manifolds in 3.26 are all smooth?

(3) Does Alexander duality imply the [Jordan-Brouwer separation theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan%E2%80%93Brouwer_separation_theorem#Generalisations) $\tilde{H}_0(\mathbb{R}^n\!\setminus\!\iota(\mathbb{S}^{n-1}))\cong\mathbb{Z}$? Can here $\iota\!:\mathbb{S}^{n-1}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n=\mathbb{S}^n\!\setminus\!\mathrm{pt}$ be a topological embedding or must it be smooth?

Answer (score 2):

You need this version of Poincaré-Lefschetz duality using Čech cohomology group.
[image]

Then you can prove the Alexander Duality 
[image]

No, this duality is true for topological manifold. 
Here is the proof of Generalized Jordan Curve Theorem. Homeomorphism is enough.
[image]

For more details, see Bredon's "Topology and Geometry" chapter 6 section 8.

Comment: So as I have stated it, Alexander manifold duality does not imply Alexander sphere duality? This seems strange, I think it should. We have $H^k(A)\cong H_{n-k}(\mathbb{S}^n, \mathbb{S}^n\!\setminus\!A)$ and exact sequence of a pair 
$0\cong H_{n-k}(\mathbb{S}^n) \longrightarrow 
H_{n-k}(\mathbb{S}^n, \mathbb{S}^n\!\setminus\!A) \longrightarrow H_{n-k-1}(\mathbb{S}^n\!\setminus\!A) \longrightarrow 
H_{n-k-1}(\mathbb{S}^n)\cong0$, but the only problem is with cases $k=0,n\!-\!1,n$. Any suggestions?